# Change ip issue

Tags: ip, cpanel, centos7, whm

I have added a new floating ip to my VPS (digital ocean - CentOs7) and I have added this in WHM and I have bind this ip to a domain. I have point domain's DNS correctly to my new ip.

But when I go in my domain I view this: 
[error page WHM cPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJkj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to access your IP through browser and check which page are you getting. if you correctly setup your domain on that IP, then you will your site home page at : http://IP

Also try to rebuild httpd configuration file on your server through following command

```
/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have tried using http://IP but I retrive the same page.
I have tried `/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf` but not working